# Problems with label and cref

Tags: theorems, labels, cleveref

I am having some (probably) beginner's problems with labeling I use:

```
\newtheorem{myprop}{Proposition}[subsection]  
\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}[subsection]  
\newtheorem{myrmk}{Remark}[subsection]
```

and so on as environments and `\label{...} \cref{...}` to label things. The problem is, I get things like `?? 1.2.3` where in place of `??` I should get `Proposition`, `Theorem` and so on. If I replace `\cref` with `\ref` then it is even worse since `??` disappears but then I lose info about whether `1.2.3` is a `Proposition`, `Theorem`...

Moreover, I would like to have links, so that by clicking I move in the document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Do you rund the `\newtheorem` statements before or after loading `cleveref`? (Hint: One should run these statements *after* loading `cleveref`.)

Comment: This was precisely the problem!!! Thanks a lot, sadly I  cannot cast you a +1

Comment: Users of this site are very strongly encouraged to provide not just code snippets but compilable code examples that replicate the issue they would like to fix. This time, my hunch about what was ailing your document happened to be correct, but it was just that: a hunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird, this works fine for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtheorem{myprop}{Proposition}[subsection]  


\begin{document}
\begin{myprop} \label{prop:hello}
    hello
\end{myprop}

\cref{prop:hello}

\Cref{prop:hello}
\end{document}
```

You should include a minimum working example to demonstrate the problem that you're having.  Also, in some situations (though perhaps not this one) the `\crefname` command and its friends can be helpful.

*EDIT*

As per Mico's request, it's important that `cleveref` is loaded before the new theorems are defined.

Comment: You should make explicit that what makes your code “work” is the fact that `\newthrorem` is executed only *after* `cleveref` is loaded.